# Google translation api for glossary is not restricting words which are defined in glossary file

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-translate, google-translation-api

Hi all could you please help me in this.I tried lots of ways but Google glossary is not working. I have created csv file with UTF-8 also tried .txt but still its not providing correct results. I am translating in Romania language from English language. PFB details & Node Js Code

**Expectations:-** cat word of English language should be translated as dog in Romania language

**Details :-**

I have created glossary and I am able to list glossary :-

**List Glossary Details :-**

**Name:**  projects/729751140979/locations/us-central1/glossaries/myglossary
**Input uri:** gs://glossary/myglossary.csv
**glossary:-**

```
{"name":"projects/729751140979/locations/us-central1/glossaries/myglossary","inputConfig":{"gcsSource":{"inputUri":"gs://glossary/myglossary.csv"},"source":"gcsSource"},"entryCount":1,"submitTime":{"seconds":"1690530203","nanos":895638998},"endTime":{"seconds":"1690530205","nanos":775226000},"di
splayName":"myglossary","languagePair":{"sourceLanguageCode":"en","targetLanguageCode":"ro"},"languages":"languagePair"}
```

Source language:- English

Target language:- Romania

File :-

[image: romania_glossary]

**Node Code for translation with glossary:-**

```
 const projectId = 'myprojectid';
 const location = 'us-central1';
 const glossaryId = 'myglossary';
 const text = 'I have a cat';

async function translateTextWithGlossary() {
  const glossaryConfig = {
    glossary: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/glossaries/${glossaryId}`,
  };
  // Construct request
  const request = {
    parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`,
    contents: [text],
    mimeType: 'text/plain', // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    sourceLanguageCode: 'en',
    targetLanguageCode: 'ro',
    glossaryConfig: glossaryConfig,
  };

  // Run request
  const [response] = await translationClient.translateText(request);

  for (const translation of response.glossaryTranslations) {
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation.translatedText}`);
  }
}

 translateTextWithGlossary();
```

**Result:-** eu am o pisică

**Expected Result:-** eu am o dog